# Quotient map from $l^1$ to a separable Banach Space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a dense subset of the unit ball $X_{\Vert \cdot \Vert\leq 1}$ and $T: l^1\rightarrow X$ with $T(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_nx_n$. If $x \in X_{\Vert \cdot \Vert < 1}$, pick $\epsilon >0$ for which $\Vert x \Vert<1-\epsilon<1$. Prove that there exists a $y \in l^1$ with $\Vert y \Vert_1<(1-\epsilon)^{-1}$ such that $T(y)= (1-\epsilon)^{-1}x$. Also prove that $T$ is a quotient map.

I proved that $T$ is a contraction map, but if there is any connection between being contraction and quotient for a map?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Being a quotient map means that it is surjective. To prove that it is surjective, you have to use the other property you mentioned, together with the fact that $T$ is bounded.

With more work and a careful choosing of the sequence $(x_n)$, one can make $T$ isometric.